Directory tree traversal results in unknown error
I created this non recursive function to read from a directory and save it's informations in an dynamic struct, together with the text files's contents.
FOLDER* scanFolder(FOLDER* pack, char* path) {
    int dirNumber = 0, result = 0, type = 0, fileCapacity = FILECHUNK, folderCapacity = FOLDERCHUNK, folderCursor = FOLDERCHUNK;
    long *dirPosition = (long*)calloc(folderCursor, sizeof(long));
    //struct stat status;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char placeholder[1024];

    if (dirPosition == NULL) {
        perror("Error allocating memory for directory cursor");
        free(dirPosition);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < folderCursor; x++) {
            dirPosition[x] = 2;
        }
    }

    DIR* scanner = opendir(path);
    if (scanner != NULL) {
        seekdir(scanner, 2);
        entry = readdir(scanner);
        strcpy(placeholder, entry->d_name);
        returnString(&path, placeholder);
    } else {
        printf("Error acessing %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    FOLDER* folder = createFolder(pack, path);
    returnString(&folder->name, "name");

    //Differentiate folder from zip file
    type = fileType(path);
    if ((type) == 0) {

        closedir(scanner);
        scanner = opendir(path);
        if (scanner != NULL) {
            seekdir(scanner, 2);
        } else {
            printf("Could not open %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
            free(dirPosition);
            return NULL;
        }
        
        while(result == 0) {
            entry = readdir(scanner);

            //Return logic
            while(entry == NULL) {
                //Reached end of contents
                if ((dirPosition[dirNumber]-2) == folder->subcount && folder->parent != NULL) {
                    if (folder->subcount > 0) {
                        FOLDER* temp = (FOLDER*)realloc(folder->subdir, folder->subcount*sizeof(FOLDER));
                        if (temp == NULL) {
                            printf("Error resizing folder %s: %s\n", folder->name, strerror(errno));

                            //Error logic
                        } else {
                            folder->subdir = temp;
                            temp = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                    if (folder->count > 0) {
                        ARCHIVE* temp = (ARCHIVE*)realloc(folder->content, folder->count*sizeof(ARCHIVE));
                        if (temp == NULL) {
                            printf("Error resizing archive %s: %s\n", folder->name, strerror(errno));

                            //Error logic
                        } else {
                            folder->content = temp;
                            temp = NULL;
                        }
                    }

                    fileCapacity = FILECHUNK;
                    folderCapacity = FOLDERCHUNK;
                    dirPosition[dirNumber] = 2;
                    dirNumber--;
                    returnString(&path, "path");
                    folder = folder->parent;
                }
                //Entering new folder
                if ((dirPosition[dirNumber]-2) < folder->subcount) {
                    folder = &folder->subdir[dirPosition[dirNumber]-2];
                    dirPosition[dirNumber]++;
                    dirNumber++;
                    returnString(&path, folder->name);

                }
                //End of loop
                if (dirNumber <= 0) {
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }

                closedir(scanner);
                scanner = opendir(path);
                if (scanner != NULL) {
                    seekdir(scanner, dirPosition[dirNumber]);
                    entry = readdir(scanner);
                } else {
                    printf("scanFolder: error openning %s %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
                }
            }

            if ((result) == 1) {
                break;
            }

            strcpy(placeholder, entry->d_name);
            returnString(&path, placeholder);
            type = fileType(path);

            //0 is folder, 1 is file
            if (type == 0) {
                //FOLDER* pointer = NULL;
                
                //New memory logic
                if (folder->subcount == 0) {
                    folder->subdir = (FOLDER*)calloc(folderCapacity, sizeof(FOLDER));

                    if (folder->subdir == NULL) {
                        perror("Error allocating memory for new folder");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                } else if (folder->subcount >= folderCapacity) {
                    folderCapacity *= 2;
                    folder->subdir = (FOLDER*)realloc(folder->subdir, folderCapacity*sizeof(FOLDER));

                    if (folder->subdir == NULL) {
                        perror("Error reallocating memory for new folder");
                    }
                }

                //pointer = createFolder(folder, placeholder);
                //folder->subdir[folder->subcount] = *pointer;
                folder->subdir[folder->subcount] = *createFolder(folder, placeholder);
                folder->subcount++;
                printf("FOLDER: %s\n", path);

            } else if (type == 1) {
                //ARCHIVE* pointer = NULL;

                if (folder->count == 0) {
                    folder->content = (ARCHIVE*)calloc(fileCapacity, sizeof(ARCHIVE));

                    if (folder->content == NULL) {
                        perror("Error allocating memory for new file");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                } else if (folder->count >= fileCapacity) {
                    fileCapacity *= 2;
                    folder->content = (ARCHIVE*)realloc(folder->content, fileCapacity*sizeof(ARCHIVE));

                    if (folder->content == NULL) {
                        perror("Error reallocating memory for new file");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                }

                //pointer = getFile(path);
                folder->content[folder->count] = *getFile(path);
                folder->count++;
                printf("FILE: %s\n", path);

            }
            returnString(&path, "path");
            
        }
        return folder;
        
    }
    return NULL;
}


These are the structs I set:
typedef struct ARCHIVE {
    char* tab;
    char* name;
    size_t size;
} ARCHIVE;

typedef struct FOLDER{
    char* name;
    struct FOLDER* parent;
    struct FOLDER* subdir;
    size_t subcount;
    size_t count;
    ARCHIVE* content;
} FOLDER;

And this is the whole code:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <minizip/zip.h>

#define FOLDERCHUNK 16
#define FILECHUNK 64

int n_folders = 0;
int n_files = 0;
int n_entries = 0;

typedef struct ARCHIVE {
    char* tab;
    char* name;
    size_t size;
} ARCHIVE;

typedef struct FOLDER{
    char* name;
    struct FOLDER* parent;
    struct FOLDER* subdir;
    size_t subcount;
    size_t count;
    ARCHIVE* content;
} FOLDER;

//Concatenate two strings to acess a path, return to the parent path or get the directory's name
void returnString (char** path, const char* argument) {
    char* scissor = strrchr(*path, '/');
    size_t lenght;

    if (scissor == NULL && (strcmp(argument, "path") == 0 || strcmp(argument, "name") == 0)) {
        scissor = strrchr(*path, '\\');
        if (strcmp(argument, "path") == 0) {
            *scissor = '\0';
        } else if (strcmp(argument, "name") == 0) {
            lenght = strlen(scissor)-1;
            memmove(*path, scissor+1, lenght*sizeof(char));
            path[0][lenght] = '\0';
        }
    } else if (scissor != NULL && (strcmp(argument, "path") == 0 || strcmp(argument, "name") == 0)) {
        scissor = '\0';
        scissor = strrchr(*path, '/');
        if (strcmp(argument, "path")) {
            *(scissor+1) = '\0';
        } else if (strcmp(argument, "name")) {
            lenght = strlen(scissor);
            memmove(*path, scissor, lenght*sizeof(char));
            path[0][lenght] = '\0';
        }
    } else {
        lenght = strlen(*path)+strlen(argument)+2;
        char* backup = strdup(*path);
        char* temp = (char*)realloc(*path, lenght*sizeof(char));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            perror("Could not reallocate memory for new path");

            if (backup != NULL) {
                *path = (char*)calloc(lenght, sizeof(char));
                if (scissor != NULL) {
                    snprintf(*path, lenght, "%s/%s", backup, argument);
                } else {
                    snprintf(*path, lenght, "%s\\%s", backup, argument);
                }
            }
        } else {
            free(backup);
            *path = temp;
            if (scissor != NULL) {
                strcat(*path, "/");
            } else {
                strcat(*path, "\\");
            }
            strcat(*path, argument);
        }
    }
}

//Check for the filetype, counting zip file
int fileType(const char* path) {
    struct stat fileStat;

    if (stat(path, &fileStat) == 0) {
        if (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode)) {
            char* pointer = strrchr(path, '.');
            if (pointer != NULL) {
                char* temp = strdup(pointer);
                if (strcmp(temp, ".zip") == 0) {
                    free(temp);
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

//Create folder
FOLDER* createFolder(FOLDER* parent, const char* name) {
    FOLDER* folder = (FOLDER*)malloc(sizeof(FOLDER));
    if (folder == NULL) {
        perror("Error creating new folder in memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    folder->name = strdup(name);
    folder->content = NULL;
    folder->subdir = NULL;
    folder->count = folder->subcount = 0;
    folder->parent = parent;
    
    return folder;
}

//Read a file into a buffer and return the ARCHIVE pointer
ARCHIVE* getFile(const char* path) {
    char *buffer, *placeholder;
    size_t bytesRead, length = 0, capacity = 1024;
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    ARCHIVE* model = (ARCHIVE*)malloc(sizeof(ARCHIVE));
    buffer = (char*)calloc(1025, sizeof(char));
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not open %s");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not allocate memory for buffer");
    }
    if (model == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not allocate memory to ARCHIVE");
    }

    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer+length, sizeof(char), 1024, file)) > 0) {
        length += bytesRead;
        if (length >= capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            placeholder = (char*)realloc(buffer, (capacity+1)*sizeof(char));
            
            if (placeholder == NULL) {
                perror("getFile: could not resize buffer");
            } else {
                buffer = placeholder;
                placeholder = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    placeholder = (char*)realloc(buffer, length*sizeof(char));
    if (placeholder != NULL) {
        buffer = placeholder;
    } else {
        placeholder = NULL;
    }

    buffer[length+1] = '\0';

    model->name = strdup(path);
    returnString(&model->name, "name");
    model->size = length;
    model->tab = buffer;

    fclose(file);
    return model;
}

FOLDER* scanFolder(FOLDER* pack, char* path) {
    int dirNumber = 0, result = 0, type = 0, fileCapacity = FILECHUNK, folderCapacity = FOLDERCHUNK, folderCursor = FOLDERCHUNK;
    long *dirPosition = (long*)calloc(folderCursor, sizeof(long));
    //struct stat status;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char placeholder[1024];

    if (dirPosition == NULL) {
        perror("Error allocating memory for directory cursor");
        free(dirPosition);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < folderCursor; x++) {
            dirPosition[x] = 2;
        }
    }

    DIR* scanner = opendir(path);
    if (scanner != NULL) {
        seekdir(scanner, 2);
        entry = readdir(scanner);
        strcpy(placeholder, entry->d_name);
        returnString(&path, placeholder);
    } else {
        printf("Error acessing %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    FOLDER* folder = createFolder(pack, path);
    returnString(&folder->name, "name");

    //Differentiate folder from zip file
    type = fileType(path);
    if ((type) == 0) {

        closedir(scanner);
        scanner = opendir(path);
        if (scanner != NULL) {
            seekdir(scanner, 2);
        } else {
            printf("Could not open %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
            free(dirPosition);
            return NULL;
        }
        
        while(result == 0) {
            entry = readdir(scanner);

            //Return logic
            while(entry == NULL) {
                //Reached end of contents
                if ((dirPosition[dirNumber]-2) == folder->subcount && folder->parent != NULL) {
                    if (folder->subcount > 0) {
                        FOLDER* temp = (FOLDER*)realloc(folder->subdir, folder->subcount*sizeof(FOLDER));
                        if (temp == NULL) {
                            printf("Error resizing folder %s: %s\n", folder->name, strerror(errno));

                            //Error logic
                        } else {
                            folder->subdir = temp;
                            temp = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                    if (folder->count > 0) {
                        ARCHIVE* temp = (ARCHIVE*)realloc(folder->content, folder->count*sizeof(ARCHIVE));
                        if (temp == NULL) {
                            printf("Error resizing archive %s: %s\n", folder->name, strerror(errno));

                            //Error logic
                        } else {
                            folder->content = temp;
                            temp = NULL;
                        }
                    }

                    fileCapacity = FILECHUNK;
                    folderCapacity = FOLDERCHUNK;
                    dirPosition[dirNumber] = 2;
                    dirNumber--;
                    returnString(&path, "path");
                    folder = folder->parent;
                }
                //Entering new folder
                if ((dirPosition[dirNumber]-2) < folder->subcount) {
                    folder = &folder->subdir[dirPosition[dirNumber]-2];
                    dirPosition[dirNumber]++;
                    dirNumber++;
                    returnString(&path, folder->name);

                }
                //End of loop
                if (dirNumber <= 0) {
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }

                closedir(scanner);
                scanner = opendir(path);
                if (scanner != NULL) {
                    seekdir(scanner, dirPosition[dirNumber]);
                    entry = readdir(scanner);
                } else {
                    printf("scanFolder: error openning %s %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
                }
            }

            if ((result) == 1) {
                break;
            }

            strcpy(placeholder, entry->d_name);
            returnString(&path, placeholder);
            type = fileType(path);

            //0 is folder, 1 is file
            if (type == 0) {
                //FOLDER* pointer = NULL;
                
                //New memory logic
                if (folder->subcount == 0) {
                    folder->subdir = (FOLDER*)calloc(folderCapacity, sizeof(FOLDER));

                    if (folder->subdir == NULL) {
                        perror("Error allocating memory for new folder");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                } else if (folder->subcount >= folderCapacity) {
                    folderCapacity *= 2;
                    folder->subdir = (FOLDER*)realloc(folder->subdir, folderCapacity*sizeof(FOLDER));

                    if (folder->subdir == NULL) {
                        perror("Error reallocating memory for new folder");
                    }
                }

                //pointer = createFolder(folder, placeholder);
                //folder->subdir[folder->subcount] = *pointer;
                folder->subdir[folder->subcount] = *createFolder(folder, placeholder);
                folder->subcount++;
                printf("FOLDER: %s\n", path);

            } else if (type == 1) {
                //ARCHIVE* pointer = NULL;

                if (folder->count == 0) {
                    folder->content = (ARCHIVE*)calloc(fileCapacity, sizeof(ARCHIVE));

                    if (folder->content == NULL) {
                        perror("Error allocating memory for new file");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                } else if (folder->count >= fileCapacity) {
                    fileCapacity *= 2;
                    folder->content = (ARCHIVE*)realloc(folder->content, fileCapacity*sizeof(ARCHIVE));

                    if (folder->content == NULL) {
                        perror("Error reallocating memory for new file");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                }

                //pointer = getFile(path);
                folder->content[folder->count] = *getFile(path);
                folder->count++;
                printf("FILE: %s\n", path);

            }
            returnString(&path, "path");
            
        }
        return folder;
        
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[0]) {
    char* path;
    path = strdup(argv[0]);
    if (path != NULL) {
        printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
        returnString(&path, "path");
        returnString(&path, "RP1");
    } else {
        printf("<%s>", argv[0]);
        perror("Invalid path");
        return 1;
    }
    FOLDER* rp = createFolder(NULL, path);
    returnString(&rp->name, "name");
    
    //Temporary, the final program will have you choose the two resourcepacks for scan
    rp->subdir = scanFolder(rp, path);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

The way it should work it's to use argv to get the file's path in the system, open the RP1 folder in the same directory and read the first target. May not be relevant, but it's a Minecraft resourcepack folder.
I am using vscode, "gcc (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r1) 14.1.0"
Besides safety pointers for allocation and reallocation of memory and skipping the file scan I am out of ideas of why it stops.
The issue happening it's that it works, but only when executing on gdb, when running the executable it stops at random points and closes.
Drmemory acused issues in readdir and seekdir, however nothing that could help me pinpoint the issue.
Error #42: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading register ax
# 0 ucrtbase.dll!wcscpy_s       +0x46     (0x00007ffdd615ef46 <ucrtbase.dll+0x2ef46>)
# 1 ucrtbase.dll!chmod          +0xc91    (0x00007ffdd61dfbd2 <ucrtbase.dll+0xafbd2>)
# 2 ucrtbase.dll!findnext64     +0x3a     (0x00007ffdd61e03db <ucrtbase.dll+0xb03db>)
# 3 _findnext64i32
# 4 readdir    
# 5 scanFolder 
# 6 main       
Note: @0:00:02.136 in thread 23288
Note: instruction: data16 test   %ax %ax


Don't post snippets of your code with dodgy descriptions such as >scanFolder function goes here. Instead provide a [mcve]. You can [edit] your question.

This char* scissor is clearly a pointer, yet further down is scissor = '\0';. Use NULL here.

@Jabberwocky I don't understand, the whole code it's in the question, the scanfolder function it's separated beacuse it's the first thing and I did not want to duplicate it. How should I do?
@WeatherVane scissor = '\0' was to place the null pointer on the array, like cutting the end of the array. If I set as null wont the pointer get the null value?

It isn't whole but fragmented, and there are no library headers. One of the first things a reader might do is to copy/paste your "whole code" and compile to see if there is anything obvious thrown up by the compiler. You've made reader guess the whole code.

The null pointer value should be NULL not a character, for readability if nothing else. It's not "cutting the array" anyway, that would be *scissor = '\0';

FYI don't call free(dirPosition) if dirPosition is NULL.

@WeatherVane I understand, mistake on my part.

So is that a bug then? scissor = '\0'; instead of *scissor = '\0';? Does it lead to dereferencing a null pointer?

@FinnDemonCat you should post your code as [mcve], IOW a minimal piece of code that can be copy/pasted/compiled without guesswork and that produces the issue. But apparently you've done the appropriate edit in the meantime, thanks.

Whenever you call a function such as strrchr you should check if it succeeded before attempting to use the result. In general, be rigorous in checking all library function calls for success.

@jarmod: there is no harm in calling free() with a null pointer.

@WeatherVane I made the change and no big difference happens, at least not that I could see. Putting scissor = NULL makes the pointer null, but the array remains the same, but *scissor = '\0' works and *scissor = NULL just gives an error on compilation.

@JonathanLeffler yes, but pointless when it's within an if (p == NULL) guard, no?

But surely you know whether you intended scissor = '\0'; to be scissor = NULL; or *scissor = '\0';? They are very different operations.

@WeatherVane yes, just a typo I missed

Stylistic point:  Rather than *(scissor+1), instead use scissor[1].  Don't fight the language.

You are using argv[0] for a purpose that's unclear to me. This will ordinarily contain the command name used to launch the program.  There are precious few conclusions that you can safely draw from this value.  It could be a simple name, a relative path, or an absolute path.  If your filesystem supports symbolic links, then it might designate a link rather then the actual executable.  There is no information about how this particular name / path was chosen.  I'm in no way confident that this is related to the problem you're asking about, but I'd consider it a problem.

It would be more usual to rely on the process's working directory, on a path passed as an argument, on an environment variable, on a path solicited from the user interactively, or perhaps even on a hardcoded path.

Your returnString() function looks like it wants to be three separate functions.  Not only are you not gaining anything internally from choosing completely different behavior based on the second argument, but you risk getting the wrong behavior under some circumstances if you happen to encounter an unfortunately-named directory.

If you ever encounter a memory allocation failure then it would be better to terminate the program than to try to recover.  For example, if returnString() fails to allocate memory, and therefore does not do the job requested of it, then how does it make sense for the program to try to continue?  The function hasn't done the required job in that case, and there's no reason to suppose that it would do if you tried again, and you wouldn't have called it if you didn't need that job done.

@JohnBollinger I understand what you mean by relying on argv to  get the current working directory. And related to returnString's argument name, if I understod it's in the unusual case somebody names a folder "name" or "path" wich I don't think it's worth bothering a solution to it. Before it was a separate function, but I wanted a all in one. It can be made better, but for now it's doing it's job. And one thing you pointed that made me remember, when testing with drmemory it aways fails to allocate more memory to path and relies on "backup", for some reason the executable doesn't do the same.

I don't think you do understand about argv[0].  The point is that it does not tell you the current working directory, or much of anything else.  If you indeed want the working directory then getcwd() is a much more direct and reliable way to get it. (That's defined by POSIX, not by the C language spec itself, but you're already using other POSIX-specific functions.)   If instead you want the location of the executable, then your best bet is to rethink the need for that.

@JohnBollinger That's a useful tip, thanks!

@jarmod: You're right — inside if (p == NULL) { …; free(p); … }, the call to free() is pointless because p is known to be NULL.  In general, however (and as you obviously know), you don't have to check whether p is not NULL before calling free()

In getFile(), your check for when to resize the buffer is incorrect.  It will trigger only when you have already overrun the buffer.

In getFile(), after reading all the file contents, you reallocate the buffer to the exact number of bytes read, then attempt to write two bytes past the end, overrunning the buffer.  Probably you should not be appending a null byte to the content in the first place, but if you do, then (1) you should make sure to allocate space for it, and (2) you should put it in the right place.

fileType() returns -1 for regular files that do not have a "." in their names.

When scanFolder() steps back upward from a subfolder to its parent, it resets fileCapacity and folderCapacity to their initial values. That's definitely incorrect for folderCapacity, and possibly incorrect for fileCapacity.  There may be other issues with that state restoration, too.  If you don't want to use recursion for this scan (and I'm fine with that), then you probably need to manage the context data for each directory in a manually managed stack.  Storage for that could be an array, maybe dynamically allocated, or a linked list.

@JohnBollinger I adressed some of your points, should it be if (length >= capacity-1)
on the check of the length of the array? And buffer[length] = '\0' is correct?
Plus, by a liked list you mean for me manage an array of structs and link the members with the pointers parent and subdir, based on where they are placed? If so, this seems a little more manageable, better with the zip file structure when I eventually get to it since it's like a list. Lastly, as you pointed out in the folder/fileCapacity variables, should I add them as members of the struct?

Important note. I may have pinpointed the issue, it may be the file condition logic, where the call to getFile happens. I ran the code on the terminal to and saw it stopped at the same point now, aways a file, and when I disabled the getFile function call the programm ran to the end.

The problem was originating from the getFile function. Removing buffer[length] = '\0'; line solves the error, a mistake in my part that I though the byte count shouldn't be subtracted one in the index.
ARCHIVE* getFile(const char* path) {
    char *buffer, *placeholder;
    size_t bytesRead, length = 0, capacity = 1024;
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    ARCHIVE* model = (ARCHIVE*)malloc(sizeof(ARCHIVE));
    buffer = (char*)calloc(1025, sizeof(char));
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not open %s");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not allocate memory for buffer");
    }
    if (model == NULL) {
        perror("getFile: could not allocate memory to ARCHIVE");
    }

    while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer+length, sizeof(char), 1024, file)) > 0) {
        length += bytesRead;
        if (length >= capacity-1) {
            capacity *= 2;
            placeholder = (char*)realloc(buffer, (capacity+1)*sizeof(char));
            
            if (placeholder == NULL) {
                perror("getFile: could not resize buffer");
            } else {
                buffer = placeholder;
                placeholder = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    placeholder = (char*)realloc(buffer, length*sizeof(char));
    if (placeholder != NULL) {
        buffer = placeholder;
    } else {
        perror("getFile: failed to shrink array");
        return NULL;
        placeholder = NULL;
    }

    model->name = strdup(path);
    returnString(&model->name, "name");
    model->size = length;
    model->tab = buffer;

    fclose(file);
    return model;
}

